# How to replace td text in VB.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have this code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlWindHailExclusionDirectDamage" Visible="False" runat="server">   
   <tr>
    <td>
      Wind/Hail Exclusion - Direct Damage:
    </td>
```

How can I manipulate the text under td tags under some given condition? I looked it up before asking but could not find a definitive answer for my question. Under given condition, I want the text to be Wind/Hail Exclusion: instead of Wind/Hail Exclusion - Direct Damage:. Help is appreciated.
PS: I looked some javascript examples but could not follow through as i have never done it before. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a class or id associated with this table? What row is this? A basic selector such as `$("tr td").text("Windo/Hail Exclusion:");` will do the trick.

Comment: If your text varies on page load, then put your text in an asp label: `<asp:Label ID="lblMyText" Visible="False" runat="server" Text="Wind/Hail Exclusion - Direct Damage:" />` Then you can change it in your code behind. If it's changed via user interaction, I'd say hit it with some jquery so the user doesn't have to suffer through a post back.

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick fiddle demonstrating the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/eBJSe/ -- I used jQuery since you tagged it in the question.

The code:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
    $("tr td:first-child").text("Windo/Hail Exclusion:");
});
```

Since you didn't post the complete table structure, I assumed this was the first td (hence the `first-child` selector). You can modify this to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Document Object Model (a way to move through an xml document)

Or you may use a dirty way and

1. Split text by vbCrLf (each item is one line)
2. Check if a line (trimmed) is
3. (in that case) Replace the next line as you plan to